# java instance variable with class name as return type

Tags: java, static, instance-variables, return-type

For the code below I have created an instance variable with class name as return type

```
class classtype{
    static classtype x;

    public static void main(String...a){
         System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Above code outputs to `null` indicating that this instance variable having class name as return type holds string type values and obviously but when i try to initialize it

```
static classtype x="1";
```

it gives type mismatch error found in `java.Lang.String`

please if anyone can explain

Comment: This is not at all clear.

Comment: "above code outputs to null indicating that this instance variable having class name as return type holds string type values" No, that's not what it indicates at all.

Comment: Note that, it's not an instance variable, but a static field. You can call it a class variable though (but that's not a standard name).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Error1:**

```
x="1";
```

You cannot do that

Because `Classtype`  is not a `String` type.

**Error2:**

Printing `null`

```
class Classtype{
         static Classtype x = new Classtype();
         public static void main(String...a){
         System.out.println(x);
         }
       }
```

Make sure that    `System.out.println(x);`  here by default prints the Objects `toString`  method.

Since your `x` haven't initialize it is null now.

So as per [print](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29)(`println` invokes `print`) method

> Prints a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

To print require `String`   `ovveride` the `toString` method in `Classtype` class.
And follow the java naming conventiones. Class names starts with caps.

With all your code becomes

```
public class Classtype {


        static Classtype x = new Classtype();
        public static void main(String...a){
        System.out.println(x);

      }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "This is ClassType toString";
        }

}
```

Comment: As Now you have covered everything. So, deleted my answer. +1

Comment: Well, that's a complement now. :)

Comment: thanx ..thats quite understandable for a java beginner :)

Comment: Reputation is just for fun :) Sharing knowledge is the the key point. Happy coding.